# How to change vaadin Radio element background color

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

[Check This](http://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!forms)

how to change the background-color of the circle itself of the radio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the `background` for `.v-radiobutton > input ~ label::before` in your theme.